# How to replace random text between a constant starting and ending string using shell command

Tags: shell

How to replace random text between a constant starting and ending string using shell command.

I have multiple line in the file with various tags

{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:xxxxhh:53B:fg :43:fg $

{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:yyyyhh:53B:fg :43:fg $

{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:zzzzz:53B:fg :43:fg $

I want to replace the text between tags :50K & :53B with common text CREDIT

Hope I am clear
Thanks
Bobby

Thanks
Bobby

Comment: Put yourself in our position and tell us if you can understand question well enough to give any answer.

Comment: Sorry Anubhava 

I have multiple line in the file with various tags

{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:xxxxhh:53B:fg :43:fg $

{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:yyyyhh:53B:fg :43:fg $

{:32tyfddf:65 trfdfd :67 ghfdfd :50K:zzzzz:53B:fg :43:fg $

I want to replace the text between tags :50K & :53B with common text CREDIT

Hope I am clear
Thanks
Bobby

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of useful information, I don't know if this is completely the right solution, but here's one possibility using `awk`:

```
awk -F: '{printf ":%s:%s:%s\n",$2,"new text",$4}' input_file.txt
```